# Java Robot in matlab mouse click.trouble

Tags: java, matlab, event-handling

I have a Java robot in Matlab going to a screen coordinate then pressing the left click. The problem is that the click only happens in the Matlab program and I need it to happen outside. If the program is open it just reopens Matlab as the open program and then clicks or if it is minimized it does nothing. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code. The problem is I am using Matlab from my university and it it like remote access is there a way then to have it recognize my computer as what it needs to work on.

```
clc;clear;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*
printbutton = [1225,800];
robot = Robot;
screenSize = get(0, 'screensize');
pause(3)
robot.mouseMove(1225,800);
pause(.5)
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Comment: what are you actually try to do with that mouse click?

Comment: Just trying to click a button on the webpage. The problem is that I'm accessing Matlab from a virtual machine and having it run on my computer instead of natively running on my computer.